# I have created calculator without eval() in javascript. Now i want to store history(previous calculations) down there

Tags: javascript, html

** As we can see below i want to store all calculations in the history id tag using js. I tried many functions but not getting to the results. I want to know which paramter should i keep inside the function addToHistory so that it can easily print the input string when i click equal sign? Please help me with that.**

```
(function () {
    const display = document.getElementById('display');

const withoutEval = (str) => {

    let arr = str.split(' ');

    switch (arr[1]) {
        case '+':
            return Math.round((+arr[0] + +arr[2]));
            break;
        case '-':
            return Math.round((+arr[0] - +arr[2]));
            break;
        case '/':

            return Math.round((+arr[0] / +arr[2]));
            break;
        case '*':
            return Math.round((+arr[0] * +arr[2]));
            break;
    };
};

let booleanSign = true;
let count = 0;
let str = '';

const keyboard = document.getElementById('keyboard');

keyboard.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    let target = e.target;

    if (target.value.match(/[0123456789\.]/)) {
        if (booleanSign === true) {
            display.textContent = '';
            booleanSign = false;
        };
        display.textContent += target.value;
        str += target.value;

    };

    if (target.value.match(/[^0123456789\.=c]/)) {
        count += 1;
        if (count === 2) {
            display.textContent = withoutEval(str);
            str = withoutEval(str);
            count = 1;
        };
        str += ' ' + target.value + ' ';
        booleanSign = true;

    };

    if (target.value.match('c')) {
        count = 0;
        booleanSign = true;
        str = ''
        display.textContent = '0';

    };


    if (target.value.match('=')) {
        count = 0;
        display.textContent = withoutEval(str);
        str = withoutEval(str);
        booleanSign = false;

        
        addToHistory();

    }; 
        
    let history = '';

    function addToHistory(value) {
         history += value;
         document.getElementById('history').innerText = history;
   }
   
   

});
```

})();

Comment: `"As we can see below i want to store all calculations in the history id tag using js"` - actually, NO. I cannot see anywhere that you attempt to store the previous calculations nor can I determine what the `history id tag` is - please clarify

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius okay now you can have a look. sorry for the inconvenience !!